# SSIS - Sharing .net dll across multiple SSIS Packages

Tags: asp.net, .net, dll, ssis, class-library

I have created a .Net library to be used for SSIS Projects. We have created number of SSIS templates all using same dotnet library.

Can someone share - how can we ensure that if we make changes to our DLL and then it reflects to all SSIS templates which we have created.

Means storing DLL centrally which everyone can refer to.

Comment: You use assembly code, register it DAC, then it shouldn't matter where your dll is, projects will find it refering to the assembly.

Comment: so registering in GAC will enable all application to use that. And if any changes to DLL is required, then again add DLL in GAC so that applications can access updated APP.

Comment: That is the plan, yes :)

Comment: The only thing you will need to do to your assembly is assign it a [strong name](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302340) and *then* you can add it to the GAC via (gacutil -if MyAssembly.dll) where gacutil should be on your Visual Studio Command Prompt Path

Comment: @ConradJagger To be clear, you are using a .Net library and not a custom component for SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you strongly sign the DLL and deploy it to GAC. Then reference it in your SSIS templates.